# automatic login without displaying the prompt for username and password in Chrome

Tags: login, google-chrome, password

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I wish to program a script that opens a browser window but bypasses the prompt for username and password and uses the already stored username and password to login automatically on the webpage.

I have been reading there should be something about some Chrome flags like

```
--auth-server-whitelist="MYIISSERVER.DOMAIN.COM" --auth-negotiate-delegatewhitelist="MYIISSERVER.DOMAIN.COM" --auth-schemes="digest,ntlm,negotiate"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29025567/how-to-enable-auto-logon-for-google-chrome-without-prompt

but is not working in any configuration of the command (of course for my URL) I have tried.

Could you give me a solution?

The following piece of code did not work:

```
google-chrome http://servername.xyz.de/start.html  --auth-server-whitelist="*xyz.de*"
```

Thank you.

Comment: The link you provided is for a Windows User. Windows and Ubuntu are 100% different. A solution for Windows will not work on Ubuntu

Comment: As far as I know the switches (flags) in Chrome apply similarly no matter of platform. Of course, it differs the manner to interpret them via command line, target string in Win etc.

Comment: doing `dpkg -L (PACKAGENAME_FOR_CHROME) | grep 'bin/'` will show you all compatible tags